# Polyglossia gives error after updating Miktex - A file which compiled flawlessly before update and the log file are attached

Tags: xetex, polyglossia

The Code I use

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=215mm,paperwidth=140mm,top=2cm,bottom=2.3cm,left=2cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{malayalam}
\setmainfont[Script=Malayalam,HyphenChar="00AD]{Rachana}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Lucida Sans Unicode}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Mangal}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\lefthyphenmin=3
\righthyphenmin=4
\raggedbottom
\sloppy
\widowpenalty=2000
\clubpenalty=2000
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{നെപ്പോളിയന്റെ നാട്ടിൽ}
\cfoot[\thepage]{\thepage}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{-2pt}
\makeatletter
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont[Script=Malayalam]{Rachana}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{1}
സ്വർണത്തിന്റെ അണുസംഖ്യ 79-ഉം പ്രതീകം Au എന്നുമാണ്. ഔറം എന്ന ലത്തീൻ വാക്കിൽ നിന്നാണ് Au എന്ന പ്രതീകം ഉണ്ടായത്.
ഏറ്റവും നന്നായി രൂപഭേദം വരുത്താൻ സാധിക്കുന്ന ലോഹമാണ് സ്വർണ്ണം. ഒരു ഗ്രാം സ്വർണ്ണം അടിച്ചു പരത്തി ഒരു ചതുരശ്രമീറ്റർ വിസ്തീർണ്ണമുള്ള ഒരു തകിടാക്കി മാറ്റാൻ സാധിക്കും.
അതായത് 0.000013 സെന്റീമീറ്റർ വരെ ഇതിന്റെ കനം കുറക്കാൻ കഴിയും. അതു പോലെ വെറും 29 ഗ്രാം സ്വർണ്ണം ഉപയോഗിച്ച് 100 കിലോ മീറ്റർ നീളമുള്ള കമ്പിയുണ്ടാക്കാനും സാധിക്കും.
\chapter{2}
സ്വർണത്തിന്റെ അണുസംഖ്യ 79-ഉം പ്രതീകം Au എന്നുമാണ്. ഔറം എന്ന ലത്തീൻ വാക്കിൽ നിന്നാണ് Au എന്ന പ്രതീകം ഉണ്ടായത്.
ഏറ്റവും നന്നായി രൂപഭേദം വരുത്താൻ സാധിക്കുന്ന ലോഹമാണ് സ്വർണ്ണം. ഒരു ഗ്രാം സ്വർണ്ണം അടിച്ചു പരത്തി ഒരു ചതുരശ്രമീറ്റർ വിസ്തീർണ്ണമുള്ള ഒരു തകിടാക്കി മാറ്റാൻ സാധിക്കും.
അതായത് 0.000013 സെന്റീമീറ്റർ വരെ ഇതിന്റെ കനം കുറക്കാൻ കഴിയും. അതു പോലെ വെറും 29 ഗ്രാം സ്വർണ്ണം ഉപയോഗിച്ച് 100 കിലോ മീറ്റർ നീളമുള്ള കമ്പിയുണ്ടാക്കാനും സാധിക്കും.
\chapter{3}
സ്വർണത്തിന്റെ അണുസംഖ്യ 79-ഉം പ്രതീകം Au എന്നുമാണ്. ഔറം എന്ന ലത്തീൻ വാക്കിൽ നിന്നാണ് Au എന്ന പ്രതീകം ഉണ്ടായത്.
ഏറ്റവും നന്നായി രൂപഭേദം വരുത്താൻ സാധിക്കുന്ന ലോഹമാണ് സ്വർണ്ണം. ഒരു ഗ്രാം സ്വർണ്ണം അടിച്ചു പരത്തി ഒരു ചതുരശ്രമീറ്റർ വിസ്തീർണ്ണമുള്ള ഒരു തകിടാക്കി മാറ്റാൻ സാധിക്കും.
അതായത് 0.000013 സെന്റീമീറ്റർ വരെ ഇതിന്റെ കനം കുറക്കാൻ കഴിയും. അതു പോലെ വെറും 29 ഗ്രാം സ്വർണ്ണം ഉപയോഗിച്ച് 100 കിലോ മീറ്റർ നീളമുള്ള കമ്പിയുണ്ടാക്കാനും സാധിക്കും.
\end{document}
```

Link to the font I use
https://smc.org.in/fonts/rachana

and a part of the log file (link to the full log file is given below)

```
Package polyglossia Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for `english'
(polyglossia)                I will use \language=\l@nohyphenation instead on i
nput line 9.

\l@english = a dialect from \language\l@nohyphenation 
Package polyglossia Info: Option: English, variant=american.
! Parameters must be numbered consecutively.
<to be read again> 
                   ##
l.143    }
          %
? r
OK, entering \nonstopmode...
! Parameters must be numbered consecutively.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.143    }
          %
I've inserted the digit you should have used after the #.
Type `1' to delete what you did use.

Runaway argument?
\etb@lst@docsvlist \@nil  american, usenglishmax, australian, newzeal\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \do was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.145 
      
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

The full log file can be downloaded from here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-nUJUDSrwTin1LGwQdiOYZYDRKaFluVn/view?usp=sharing

When I trace the error, it goes to the file gloss-english.ldf

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Please make sure your example can be tested by others. we don't have those files you are including. And we are unlikely to have the fonts you use. Additionally please provide the entire log, not just a sniplet as it can tell us a lot of important information about your system.

Comment: Okay, sorry for that mistake....I shall update

Comment: I have updated the post with the links to the font and full logfile

Comment: Something is wrong with the english patterns. Check the status of the languages in the miktex console.

Comment: Miktex console shows English ticked, Loader : hyphen.tex, Package: knuth-lib and installed ticked

Comment: You can see which patterns have been preloaded with `\documentclass{minimal} \usepackage[showlanguages]{babel} \stop`. With this minimal ‘document’ a list is written to the `log` file (with XeTeX tabs are written as ^^I, but I think it's readable enough).

Comment: The log file is uploaded here :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/144NnJYaESPg5ljcVGhm8PgVDk3pM1e8j/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I could solve the issue. It was about updating miktex as administrator and user.  I guess both were different. After sorting it out, everything works fine